# Cannot update quantity from cart

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, quantity

I've been working on a Magento website: satcogrowlight.com

I am very new to working with Magento in the back end.

My problem is that once I've added an item to my cart, I cannot change the quantity in the cart. I enter in the new quantity, click "Update Shopping Cart", the page refreshes, and everything remains the same.

I have no idea where to start troubleshooting. I haven't made any changes to the code, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to include the form key,in cart.phtml.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost')?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" >
</form>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. For future readers: The location of this file is /app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/checkout

Comment: So many templates to update, but it's a good thing to have the form key to prevent attacks.